# What is surface pattern, template pattern and ensemble pattern in NLP text matching?

Tags: nlp, data-mining

I am working on text matchign using NLP. I have used fuzzywuzzy and cosine similarity.

Someone asked me about surface pattern, template patterns, ensemble pattern approach.

What is that?

Comment: Pl do not [cross-post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/29641/11097) :)

Comment: @Dawny33: okay, do you have answer?